# Shuffle list to maximize minimum distance between new and original positions

Tags: python

I am looking for a simple way that will allow to re-order elements in a Python list in such a way so that each new element position is as far as possible from its original position, in a way that takes all element positions into account.

I should also be able to restore the original positions. For this reason, random should not be used.

I tried to solve this by reversing the order of the list but the middle elements are very close to their original positions and that is not optimal.

Instead, I am looking for a calculated way that takes all element positions into account and maximizes the minimum distance between the new positions and the original positions.

Comment: So you are trying to maximise the sum of distances, not the minimal distance or the sum of square distances or anything fancy? In that case, it is fine that the distance between some elements is zero. Reversing seems to be the best solution, with average distance of L/2.

Comment: Did you try rotating the items by half the length of the list ? This would make them all be at least half the length away from their original position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sole metric is to optimize the minimum distance from the original position, then the optimal solution is this.

```
def shuffle(lst):
    length = len(lst)
    return lst[length//2:] + lst[:length//2]
```

That is, shift the list forward by `floor(length / 2)` positions, wrapping around if we hit the end. So `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` becomes `[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]`.

Every element is moved `floor(length / 2)` positions away from its starting point.

We can't do better than this, because there's no way to move the middle elements further than `floor(length / 2)`, so the minimum distance is always at least `floor(length / 2)`.

Comment: This is fine, but if only average distance is important, it is no better than reversing the list.